# Correlation Id for listener while using Serilog in .Net core

Tags: logging, .net-core, correlation, serilog

I am having a .net core console app which is a listener for RabbitMQ. Also I am using Serilog for logging. The API which pushes message into the queue adds a Correlation ID as one parameter in the message. While writing the logs, I want the CorrelationID (as specified in the output template of serilog config) to be replaced with the one available in the message, to track the operation end to end. Can anybody suggest a way to achieve this?

Note: If it is a web request, Serilog provided middlewares (Scoped Middleware or LogContext) come to the rescue. However, they require HttpContext (for obvious reasons). For this kind of listener request, I am stuck to find a solution

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the point where you pick up the message, you should be able to to

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("corrId", msg.CorrId))
    ProcessMessage(msg)
```

You can also [add a `....|{Properties}` element into your log format string](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#formatting-plain-text) to pick up any properties not used in the message template associated with a given message (but it sounds like you have that covered)

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. This works like a charm.

Comment: Would like to know whether this can be moved out of the main code (like how we use a middleware in web apps). This is just to ensure for the other modules to replicate the same in a common place like Startup.cs, instead of finding the exact location of ProcessMessage to include this change

Comment: yes, you can make a middleware out of it if its a natural thing that's 1:1 with HTTP req processor, but I'd say for a message processing loop, doing it inline is a natural place for this to go - the `Dispose` layering can be important so best have it inline would be my default approach

Comment: Sure Ruben. Thanks for your suggestion